# Regarding the first words/speech of Allah سُبْحَانَهُ وَتَعَالَى on judgement day

Tags: hadith, allah, day-of-judgement

since childhood we keep hearing that on judgement day our creator will judge between us, more specifically, talk to us and have (secret) conversations with us. this talk and conversations as i understand includes mainly questioning (about our sins).

until recently i did not know there was a record/narration/hadith regarding the first words/speech of Allah سُبْحَانَهُ وَتَعَالَى to the believers on the day of judgement.

can someone from the community please enlighten me about this. is this true?, if so what is the narration/hadith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asalaam alaikum**

There are so many narrations/ahadith about Allah ﷻ speaking on the resurrection day. Some are before taking accounts and some are after. As you have specifically asked for the first words/speech of Allah ﷻ to the believers on judgement day, I believe this might be relevant.

> Mu’aadh ibn jabal related that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ said, “if you wish, I will inform you of the first (words) Allahﷻ will say to the believers on the Day of Resurrection and the first (words) you will say to Him”. The companions said, “yes, O Messenger of Allah”. He said, “indeed Allahﷻ will say to the believers, ‘Did you love to meet me?’, They will say, ‘Yes, O our Lord’. He will say, ‘And what made you (want) that?’. They will say, ‘Your forgiveness, Your Mercy, Your Pleasure’. He will say, ‘I have made My Mercy to be obligatory for you.” *(Abu Dawood)*

**REFERENCE**

*the following narration is extracted from  **book of the end : great trials and tribulations** by Ibn Kathir* page 371 under the topic THE FIRST SAYING OF ALLAH ﷻ TO THE BELIEVERS.

*May Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.*

**Allahﷻ knows best**

Comment: this is new information to me, thank you so much brother.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different verses about the Day of Judgment and the reckoning of the servants. But the verses about God talking to His servants on the Day of Judgment are generally general. For example, God speaks to some criminals and infidels on the Day of Judgment : "He will say, ‘Begone in it, and do not speak to Me!" 23_verse 108
On the other hand, Abu Dharr narrates from the Prophet of God (PBUH) that he said: In the resurrection of God, he does not speak to three people: He who gives blessings does not give anything to anyone unless he gives blessings and he who leaves his skirt (long skirt) And who is the one who sells his goods by false oath.

It is also mentioned in a verse of the Qur'an that on the Day of Resurrection, the people of Hell, who disbelieved in God in life, rebelled, and became enemies with him, does not comment or speak at all: " There shall be no share in the Hereafter for those who sell Allah’s covenant and their oaths for a paltry gain, and on the Day of Resurrection Allah will not speak to them nor will He [so much as] look at them, nor will He purify them, and there is a painful punishment for them." 3_verse 77

Comment: i am searching specifically for a narration that states such, i am sure i have heard it somewhere but not able to recall or verify it. thank you for your effort.